# Longevity of entries in /tmp on a server

Tags: linux, configuration, tmp

On a server that's up 24/7/365: where and how are the cleanup of /tmp (and /var/tmp) defined / controlled / configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general that is entirely up to the distribution you are using, but you can assume that if something is being deleted it is  done from a cronjob, and surely runs from `/etc/cron.daily` (could also be `cron.weekly` or `/etc/cron.d`).

If `tmpwatch` is installed then that is what is erasing your files and directories. In its most simple way it is executed as `tmpwatch <hours> <dir1> [<dir2>, ...]`

Another variant is `tmpreaper`.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Torian's suggestion of using `tmpwatch`. One thing to watch (har har) out for is that `tmpwatch` uses file atime by default to decide if a file should be deleted. If you are mounting your `/tmp` partition with `noatime` this can lead to problems. Use `relatime` instead, particularly since newer kernels have a much smarter handling of this flag.

Comment: the atime thing could really create ulcers ;)